# How to load flex swf from flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

I have some swf compiled in flex I want to load it into my movie clip in flash pro.

...So how to for example load flex swf inside Flash CS4?

how to do such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can read more about it:
http://troygilbert.com/2009/05/loading-flex-based-swfs-in-as3-only-swfs/

Here is the code for loading the flex swf:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("my-flex-app.swf"));
loader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isBootstrapRoot", systemManagerHandler);
loader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isStageRoot", systemManagerHandler);

function systemManagerHandler(event:Event):void { event.preventDefault(); }
```

Comment: But how to set resolution to thet flex swf (it was 100% to 100%) and now I want to set it to 500 to 100 but it just keeps being square...

Comment: what do you mean with setting the resolution? Once you load the swf you can set it's dimensions as any other display object, so loadedSwf.width or loadedSwf.scaleX change them accordingly.