# Load Flex4 application in Flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have created a plugin-enabled flash which reads a configuration file and loads several other  flash files. All the files have been created by Adobe Flash CS5 . Recently i had to create a flex application which i want to load on stage of the main flash.

```
this.addChild(this.movieLoader);
this.movieLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadedM);
this.movieLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
this.movieLoader.load(new URLRequest(fmovie));
```

The LoadedM(..) is triggered every time and the loaded flash is placed into stage and positioned in LoadedM(..) .

When i load a FlashCS5 created swf, the loader.content is of type [object MainTimeline] while when i load the Flex4 application the loader.content is of type [object _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager]

My problem is that the flex application is not visible on stage nor the initialized/created events of the flex app are triggered even thow debug shows full load of the file.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354612/how-to-load-flex-swf-from-flash) solution but didnt do any good. i've checked the Event.INIT event of the loaded instead of Event.INIT and it's being triggered. But the anthropod debugged doest not report the the initialization of the flex app take place.

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354612/how-to-load-flex-swf-from-flash

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about the problem at http://old.troygilbert.com/2009/05/loading-flex-based-swfs-in-as3-only-swfs/

If the above does not work, make sure that you are publishing your swf for flashplayer 10.2+

Comment: I've already tried that solution (i've mentioned it in the post above but forgon to add the link)...  doesn't work!

Comment: But a comment on your link helped. I was publishing the flashCS5.5 with "Flash Player 10 & 10.1". I republised it with 10.2 and the flex app loaded smoothly.

Comment: Good to know. I set that as the answer for the next person who has the problem.